# Unable to export variables within function expressjs/requestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My export code

```
//export.js    
var express = require('express'),
    fs      = require('fs'),
    request = require('request'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    app     = express();

    var episode = [],
        title = [],
        synopsis = [],
        reviews = [],
        date = [];

exports.showGrab = function(url,response){
    request(url,response, function(error, response, html){

       var $ = cheerio.load(html),
            shows = {bitten:['http://www.tv.com/shows/bitten-2013/episodes/']};
        $('.no_toggle._clearfix').eq(1).filter(function(){
            var data = $(this);
                episode = data.children().first().children().last().text();
                exports.episode = episode;
        })
    })
}
console.log(episode); // => defined as [] not the value given in the function 

//import.js
var express = require('express'),
    fs      = require('fs'),
    request = require('request'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    app     = express(),
    server  = require('./export');


console.log(server.episode);
server.showGrab('http://www.tv.com/shows/bitten-2013/episodes/');
```

within the import script using the function `server.showGrab` works fine but I need access to the variables within the show grab function in my import script. I believe this problem boils down to a scope issue, if I export variables outside a function they work fine but I was under the impression that declaring variables the way I have done would make them global. How can I run this function in the import script whilst still passing it a url and getting back `episode` to work with?

Comment: It's not a scope issue, it's a timing issue.

Comment: so how would you go about solving the problem? set a timer interval on my export perhaps? or is there a way in node to wait until action, ie wait until the function has finished before assigning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pointy you were right the import script was calling the value before it was defined

```
//import.js
if (server.episode === undefined){
var test = setInterval(function(){
        if (server.episode != undefined){
            clearInterval(test);
        }
        console.log(server.episode);
    }, 1000);
}
```

this does the trick, for some reason using else instead of wrapping an if in an if does not work.